# Printf prints old buffer - C

Tags: c, printf

I'm creating a server/client. The clent sends a message to the server, which stores it into a file. Than the client can read this message.
So, I'm using only the following functions (plus the bind etc): fgets, read (both for read from socket and file) write (to write on files/socket). And printf to print.

The strange thing is that when I call a printf, it happens that it prints an old text. So, for example if I decided to delete all the message, I'll receive from the server a string like "file deleted". Then in the following action, when there's a printf it happens that it prints the desider content plus a part of the previous pessage, like "file dele". How is this possible? What should I check in my code? I'd get things right without using things like fflush(stdout);.

Comment: This is completely impossible to answer with out some code to look at.

Comment: It could be simple buffering, in which case `fflush(stdout);` will do the trick. Make sure your lines end with a `\n`.

Comment: Show us some code, the part that retrieves the data to print. Otherwise, we know nothing.

Comment: Are you using scanf()? Sometimes that function can hold some garbage in the buffer if it doesn't get a newline character.

Comment: @user3270760 No, I'm not using any scanf, only fgets.
PiotrZierhoffer arusidante: will post code as soon as I get the chance. But from a theorical side, I've used only something like 4 functions/sys calls, so it's possible to figure out some solutions?

Comment: @user3270760: `fflush` on an input stream has undefined behavior.

Comment: you're right, sorry. Would getchar() do the trick?

Comment: @daimpa ``'I've only used four functions...'``. The entirety of every program ever written can theoretically boil down to a series of ``NAND`` operations, which is a single function call. The point being, there are many, many, many, *MANY* ways programming can go wrong, especially a language like C that has so many ways to shoot yourself in the foot. So no, just because you 'only' use 4 functions (which happen to be some of the easiest functions to misuse), doesn't mean we can come up with *meaningful* solutions. We'd just be guessing, so you might as well just read a tutorial/documentation.

Comment: There are a milloin things you can do in C which mess up things... So, for a list of things to check: check that you understand every line and that you know what each function does when called with the arguments you call them with. Once you understand and know all this, finding the bug should be easy...

Answer (score 1):

You should check for proper '\0' termination.